# My Object's date value is changing when pass through server side

Tags: java, date, servlets, gwt, glassfish-3

My problem is about date value of my object which get through from web side into server side. If necessary to explain, I have an object and it has property which keep date.So when i debug on GWT side my date value is correct that i selected. After the object pass through on servlet, it becomes different. I use glassfish 3 and can it be relate to server's date, timezone or something? If you need to more specific information, please ask me. Respect.

Comment: How do you know that it is different? Do you print it somewhere?

Comment: Add some code and give us the date values that are different. You might also want to try to show the millis instead of a date, maybe formatting is different.

Comment: I see it's different because i debug server and cilent side at the same time, so i observe the difference. By the way i forget to say that difference is only in HH:mm:ss part. yyyy-MM-dd part is ok. I select date value from date picker and i put this value into my object date property. When i debug, i see it's same value as i selected before i call servlet. After it pass throug servlet side, i see it's different. For example i select 09/10/2014 10:10 from date picker, and it is looked as 09/10/2014 02:40 as servlet.